# Fetch variable from php with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a php file which contains the following code:

```
 function render() {
    //fetches all the data from input.
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
    $database = mysql_select_db("guestbook");
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $post = $_POST['post'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO gast(name, email, post, date) VALUES('$name','$email','$post','$date')";
    $input = mysql_query($sql);
    mysql_close($con);
}
```

With javascript, I'd like to retrieve those variables, something like this:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = clicked;
    function clicked() {
    var name = document.render.name.value;
    var post = document.render.post.value;
    var email = document.render.email.value;
    }
```

I have included that javascript code in my body, but it doesn't work. How do I get the value?

Comment: You can't access php function with javascript :) if you want to access data, use ajax

Comment: PHP runs on the server, javascript runs on the client, so they have no access to each other, and indeed don't "run" at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Use AJAX. With jQuery you can get any data from the server very easy.

```
$.get('test.php', function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really, unless the js and php code is on the same page, then you could do

```
var namn = "<?php echo $name; ?>";
```

but unless the php is passing the variables to the file that your js is in, you can't really do anything.